# Merge values and properties from one object into another

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, lodash

I have two separate objects:

**Object 1**

```
var obj1 = {
    features: {
        "1234": {
            "price": 0
        },
        "1235": {
            "price": 0
        }
    }
};
```

**Object 2**

```
var obj2 = {
    features: {
        "1234": {
            "price": 1000,
            "property": "val"
        },
        "1235": {
            "price": 500,
            "property": "val"
        }
    }
};
```

I want to set the price property of **Object 1** to the value of the price property of **Object 2** where the keys (1234, 1235, etc..) match in both objects.

Additionally, I'm wondering how do I add a new property to **Object 1** from **Object 2**.

In the end I would like **Object 3** to look like:

```
var obj3 = {
    features: {
        "1234": {
            "price": 1000,
            "property": "val"
        },
        "1235": {
            "price": 500,
            "property": "val"
        }
    }
};
```

I've tried the following, but there must be a better way that works?

```
var obj3 = {};
for (key in obj1) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var val = obj1[key];
        if (typeof val === 'object') {
            for (obj1_key in val) {
                if (val.hasOwnProperty(obj1_key)) {
                    if (obj1_key === 'price') {
                        // set value to value of obj2 price property
                    }

                    // add a new property to object #3
                    obj3[obj1_key]['property'] = 'value_of_object_2_property';
                }
            }
        }
        // add to new object #3
        obj3[key] = val;
    }
}
```

I understand there are libraries to help with this sort of thing such as underscore so if you have recommendations on how to achieve this with underscore or lodash I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: first thing that comes to mind is a recursive function to traverse an object and it's values.

Comment: I thought so too, but I haven't yet worked out how I would do that.  I was hoping that javascript has some magical methods that could help achieve this.

Comment: JS is definitely missing these methods in it's standard libraries. :<

Comment: Maybe so: `var obj3 = { features: ob2.prices };`

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be drilling into `obj1.features` and `obj2.prices`.

Comment: @AlexanderMac I wish it were that easy, unfortunately both object 1 and 2 have properties that I have omitted.  And the end result (object 3) needs to retain properties (and objects) from object 1 and adopt values and properties from object 2 :(

Comment: So `obj3` needs to have all the properties from `obj1` and `obj2`, except that `obj1.features` and `obj2.prices` need to be merged when copying to `obj3.features`?

Comment: If you use jQuery, `$.extend` can be used for this.

Comment: Close, obj3 needs to have all properties of obj1 AND it needs to adopt only 1 property from obj2.  Additionally ob3 needs to have a few values changed that are inherited from obj2.  I hope I'm explaining this correctly.  And unfortunately no jQuery here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with lodash. In boths solutions, you can extract any fields from `obj2` with `_.pluck` function.

Solution 1, with loop by `obj1` fields:

```
var obj3 = { features: {} };
_(obj1.features)
    .keys()
    .each(function(id) {
       var price = ob2.prices[id];
       if (price) {
         obj3.features[id] = _.pick(price, ['price', 'property']);
       }
    })
    .value();
```

Solution 2, with using `reduce` function:

```
var obj3 = _.reduce(ob1.feature, function(result, value, id) {
  var price = ob2.prices[id];
  if (price) {
    result.features[id] = _.pick(price, ['price', 'property']);
  }
  return result;
}, { features: {}});
```

Comment: Np, yes lodash it's a best library for working with objects and collections.

Answer (score 0):

Use [_.merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge)

> This method is like _.assign except that it recursively merges own and inherited enumerable string keyed properties of source objects into the destination object. Source properties that resolve to undefined are skipped if a destination value exists. Array and plain object properties are merged recursively.Other objects and value types are overridden by assignment. Source objects are applied from left to right. Subsequent sources overwrite property assignments of previous sources.

```js
var obj1 = {
    features: {
        "1234": {
            "price": 0
        },
        "1235": {
            "price": 0
        }
    }
};

var obj2 = {
    features: {
        "1234": {
            "price": 1000,
            "property": "val"
        },
        "1235": {
            "price": 500,
            "property": "val"
        }
    }
};

var obj3 = {};
_.merge(obj3,obj1,obj2);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj3,null,2);
console.log(obj3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id='result'></pre>
```